# Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed weighted graph with $w:E \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $v \in V$. How can I find all negative/positive cycles containing $v$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed weighted graph with $w:E \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $v \in V$. How can I find all negative/positive cycles containing $v$?

Comment: when is a cycle positive? when negative?